# Yandex map Symbol Polyline (Возможность нарисовать линию в виде точек)

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Нужна помощь, столкнулся с проблемой отображения polyline strokeStyle в виде точек (окружности)
Согласно описанию: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1-dev/ref/reference/graphics.style.stroke-docpage/
dot-точки
Но на примере совсем не точки
Пример:[stroke-ymaps-polyline](http://jsfiddle.net/Novakand/r37kq82m/11/)
Также наблюдается зависание браузер при увеличении зума карты.
В технической поддержке сообщили что проблема актуальна!
Возможно ли использовать Symbol в Polyline как Google maps?

```
var walkingLineSymbol = {
                        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                        fillOpacity: 1,
                        scale: 3
                    };

                    var WalkingStart = new google.maps.Polyline({
                        path: [],
                        strokeColor: '#007bff',
                        strokeOpacity: 0,
                        fillOpacity: 0,
                        icons: [{
                            icon: walkingLineSymbol,
                           offset: '0',
                          repeat: '10px'
                        }],
                    });
```